# None of them "has" or "have"

Tags: sentence-construction, subject-verb-agreement, plural-forms

Is "none" singular or plural? I understand it to mean **no one** which is obviously singular. But I have seen sentences like:

- **None** of them **have** seen it

which equals:

- **No one** of them **have** seen it

The subject is singular but we use the plural form "have"

I haven't seen "has" used in this sentence.

Which one is more correct? Are both correct? What about its grammar (should it be "has" or "have")?

Comment: In examples like yours, "none" occurs freely with either singular or plural agreement. Did you look in a dictionary? See here: [link](https://www.lexico.com/definition/none)

Comment: Btw, in your particular example,"none" is not the same as "no one" (it's actually closer to "not one"). "None of them **has** seen it" is just as correct as "None of them **have** seen it".